# How to use notification intent in Activity, when app is opened

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to read the notification data in app activity. If the app is closed, I am sending notification and opens app onclick. This works fine and I am getting data. I am extracting intent in onCreate.

But I don't know how can I read intent if the app is opened. onNewIntent() is not working.

```
  if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                    // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                    Log.e("GROUND", "BACK");
                    Intent pushNotification = new Intent(AppConfig.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                    // play notification sound
                    NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                    notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
                } else {
                    // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                    Log.e("GROUND", "FOR");
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecurityMainActivity.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);


                }
```

Comment: Please post more code. Currently it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve and what you are asking.

Comment: are you running the SecurityMainActivity as singleTop?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes.

Comment: so, can you explain what is not working on new intent?

Comment: @Okas I want to just read the broadcasted intent AppConfig.PUSH_NOTIFICATION, from within the activity

Comment: You have to register BroadcastReceiver to receive notifications sent by LocalBroadcastManager. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/3964585